# error msg NETSDK1129:Publish target is not supported without specifying a target framework, project is targeting multiple frameworks

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, .net-4.8

I am getting this error while building a CI pipeline in Azure devOps
The error message NETSDK1129: The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework suggests that your project is targeting multiple frameworks, and during the publishing process, the build system is unable to determine which framework to use for publishing.

this is my yaml file

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  name: default

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  project: '**/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: NuGetTool Installer
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '4.9.6' 
    checkLatest: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(project)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: false
```

Answer (score 1):

> NETSDK1129: The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework suggests that your project is targeting multiple frameworks

Dotnet publish does not support using multiple TargetFrameworks at the same time.

You can check the **TargetFrameworks** field in the csproj files and confirm if they are using TargetFrameworks.

For example:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You can add the argument: **--framework xxx** in the dotnet publish task to define the single target framework.

For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(project)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --framework net5.0'
    zipAfterPublish: false
```